# How to get blank input with scanf

Tags: c

I have created a console-based program that get commands from the user. I wanted to check if the user give a blank input (just hit enter), it gives a message to the user. I used wscanf_s to get input from users. I have written the following code:

```
        else if (!wcscmp(g_c_Commands, L"console"))
        {
            wchar_t console_command[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
            wscanf_s(L"%s", console_command, MAX_PATH - 1);

            if (!wcscmp(console_command, L"--local"))
            {
                CallPsExecuteWindow(arg_computer_name);
            }
            else if (!wcscmp(console_command, L"--ip"))
            {
                wchar_t remote_host[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
                wscanf_s(L"%s", remote_host, MAX_PATH - 1);
                CallPsExecuteWindow(remote_host);
            }
            else
            {
                wprintf(L"\n\t");
                WarningMessage(L"%s", L"[Wrong] Usage: console --local / --ip [ADDRESS].");
                wprintf(L"\n\n");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just look for a `\n`.  `if(strlen(console_command) == 1 && console_command[0] == '\n')`

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please learn [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [how not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) before posting a question. We need to understand the problem correctly *and* entirely so please add all the necessary details that clarify your issue and/or (when related to code) post a [minimal complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MCRE) with the actual and expected behavior as well as (if possible) the actual input.

Comment: @ryyker it doesn't work.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio How can I process blank input in C programs.

Comment: In my program, I used scanf continuously, unfortunately, scanf doesn't properly work with fgets altogether because I use scanf as the main tool to get input. If I wanted to change to fgets, I should edit the whole project which I can't do it now.

Comment: @user3121023 Thank you, Solved it with this trick.

Comment: If anything, the spate of "how to do basic I/O using the C/C++ standard library api" is an indication of how terribly broken those APIs are. All this crap should have been deprecated decades ago. Dear ai000-ckl: don't ever think any worse about yourself if you get problems with those default APIs. They are horrible to use, and even professionals have to check in the man pages to make sure they haven't gotten it wrong, and even then they often still do get it wrong. The "basic" C and C++ I/O functions should be nuked from orbit. They are wicked and unredeemable. Yuck. Same goes for C strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `"%s"`, you should use `"%[^ \t\n]"` after skipping blanks:

```
console_command[0] = L'\0';
wscanf_s(L"%*[ \t]");  // skip blanks if any
wscanf_s(L"%[^ \t\n]", console_command, (unsigned)MAX_PATH); // read word, stop on white space
```

The first `wscanf_s` will fail if no blanks are pending, but you can ignore the error.

The second `wscanf_s` will fail if there are no more words pending on the line, ie: if the pending byte is a newline, `console_command` is unmodified so it still contains an empty string.

---

Parsing this input as wide strings is a major pain, most platforms have standardized on UTF-8 encoding, it is a shame you must deal with such cumbersome APIs.

It is also very disturbing to have to pass a `unsigned int` value as the number of elements in the destination array when the C Standard specifies that this extra argument should be a `size_t` which has a different width on most 64-bit platforms including Windows.